# java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tv.app.exoui.DemoApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Application

Tags: android, proguard

I am trying to create a ***release build*** for my project. After generating the release-apk, when I install and launch it, it gives me the following error

```
06-20 17:45:47.629   800   861 I WindowManager: B2026652 WAR. Hide the surface com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity
06-20 17:45:47.637 14162 14162 D AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.tv.app, PID: 14162
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.tv.app.exoui.DemoApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tv.app.exoui.DemoApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Application
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:971)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5816)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1662)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6592)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime: Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.tv.app.exoui.DemoApplication cannot be cast to android.app.Application
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1101)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:1086)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:965)
06-20 17:45:47.639 14162 14162 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 9 more
06-20 17:45:47.644   800   861 I WindowManager: B2026652 WAR. Hide the surface com.google.android.tvlauncher/com.google.android.tvlauncher.MainActivity
```

But when I run the same code in ***debug build***, I am not getting this error

While building release build proguard showed some warnings, since the app was working fine in debug build I gave **~ignorewarnings** in proguard-rules.pro, could this be an issue?

Code :

```
    public class DemoApplication extends Application {
    ...
    }
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="false"     
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name=".exoui.DemoApplication"
    android:testOnly="false">
```

Comment: `I gave ~ignorewarnings in proguard-rules.pro, could this be an issue?` yes, but it doesn't mean it *the* issue this time. :) Although 90%+ of the times a Release build crashes (vs a Debug build), chances are Proguard/minify did it. So you'll need to blow the dust out of your warnings that you covered with the ignore flag, and start seeing what is causing a Warning to begin with :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Sure I will check the warnings generated by proguard.

Comment: Although 90%+ of the times a Release build crashes. Can u explain this a bit? In which scenario does this happen?

Comment: When a Release build (that went through any form of post-compile optimization) like minify, proguard, multi-dex, etc. crashes, it's more often than not, the cause of the source code being modified after it was built. A common example is proguard, since it tends to remove/shrink/obfuscate code, public APIs get modified and/or methods removed and when the runtime code executes, said methods (that were there at compile time) are no longer there. That's why I always recommend my clients to run their unit tests in RELEASE builds :)

Comment: My app still crashes with the same error (after removing all those warnings given by proguard)

Comment: there is too little information provided to understand this, for example the proguard configuration rules. this could as well be a multidex/proguard issue, with a class inside the wrong one dex file... what do you mean by "removing all those warnings"; did you mute them?

Comment: yes i think I have muted them. I used **-dontwarn packagename** option in proguard file to remove those warnings. Like for example    
-dontwarn org.apache.harmony.**     
-dontwarn com.android.org.**   
-dontwarn com.android.i18n.**

Comment: Well then you didn't change anything. The warning are there to, ahem,  **warn** you of potential problems.

Comment: I have no clue how to fix warings like these **Warning: com.android.server.sip.SipHelper: can't find referenced class javax.sip.SipFactory**. I am new to proguard, so if you can point me towards a good tutorial where I can learn about all these, that would be great